# Jquery/JS Select last td in each line which don't have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to get all last  elements which don't have the "treegrid-hide-column" class in each  line.

How can in do that in CSS or JS ?

I tried doing that but it doesn't works well.

```
function addRightBorderOnTreetable() {
    var arr = $('.treegridCustom tbody tr td:last-child');
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var currentEl = arr[i];
        if ( !$(currentEl).hasClass("treegrid-hide-column") ) {
            $(currentEl).css('border-right', '1px solid #bfbfbf');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to select `td`'s with value 2, 5, 8 ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very active place. When you post a question (or answer), *stick around* for a few minutes to answer requests for clarification such as @Pugazh's above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS doesn't have this feature, but you can do it with jQuery:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find("td:not(.treegrid-hide-column):last").each(function() {
    $(this).css('border-right', '1px solid #bfbfbf');
  });
});
```

```js
$("tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find("td:not(.treegrid-hide-column):last").each(function() {
    $(this).css('border-right', '1px solid #bfbfbf');
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

We have to go row-by-row because there's no CSS "last element not matching this class", and jQuery's `:last` applies to the whole set, not the set at each level of thes elector.

Comment: What about `nth-last-child()` ?

Comment: @MrAlb: That would only work if **all** rows have the class in the last child (which is what's shown, but the question is phrased such that it seems like it may not always be the case).

Answer (score 0):

If you added a class to your preferred `td` ?

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="right-border">2</td>
        <td class="treegrid-hide-column">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="right-border">5</td>
        <td class="treegrid-hide-column">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td class="right-border">8</td>
        <td class="treegrid-hide-column">9</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And then change the css

```
.right-border {
      border-right: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

Or with a `js` function

```
function addRightBorderOnTreetable() {
    var el = $('.treegridCustom tbody tr .right-border');
    el.css('border-right', '1px solid #bfbfbf');
}
```

Comment: Why downvote this answer? It's a perfectly valid approach, and avoids the need for using script. Maybe the HTML can't be adjusted, but that doesn't make the suggestion a bad one.

Comment: Perhaps wants dynamically finding the last  `td` without `treegrid-hide-column` but with the information given I gave a workaround.Probably he does not know how the downvote system works.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to run for loop like this. I think this is what you want to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
addRightBorderOnTreetable();
});

function addRightBorderOnTreetable() {
   
    $.each($('tr'),function(){
        var arr2 = $(this).find('td');
         
        var j = arr2.length;
        for(j=arr2.length; j>-1;j--){
        var currentEl = arr2[j - 1];
          if (!$(currentEl).hasClass("treegrid-hide-column") ) {
            $(currentEl).css('border-right', '1px solid #bfbfbf');
            return;
          }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td class="treegrid-hide-column">9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

So simple use `nth-last-child()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $( 'table tbody tr td:nth-last-child(2)').css('border-right', '1px solid #bfbfbf'); 
    });
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7L5ukyu/)

Comment: What if the elements selected by `nth-last-child(2)` also have the `treegrid-hide-column` class? The question was not "how do I select the second last child?". This is not a generic solution.

Comment: @trincot I just found a solution based on the above table.But YES you are RIGHT this is not a generic solution.Depends on the table format.@T.J.Crowder answer is correct and  include all the 'cases'

Answer (score -2):

```
   table tr td:not(.treegrid-hide-column):last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    }
```

Comment: This won't match any element in the OP's example. Remember: A CSS compound selector is an "**and**".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ??

Comment: Have you? Again: It doesn't work. Perhaps you misread the question. (Which is easily done.)